# Jquery left click event with cell

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Example code: Simple Context Menu

This pop up opening after right click on link.. but same result want to get after clicking on any cell in the website.

```
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var m = "clicked: " + key;
            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('clicked', this);
    })
});

<div class="context-menu-one box menu-1">
    <strong>right click me</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Plz, answering your question out of goodwill. Reply will happen as soon as someone has an answer.

Comment: need modification in this code

Comment: What do you mean 'every cell'? Do you mean anywhere on the page?

Comment: They're not cells, they're DOM elements. Cells are in tables or living things.

Answer (score 1):

To have your script fire on the entire page, change your selector:

```
selector: 'body',
```